# How can I start a disabled service@ in Fedora 38?

Tags: systemctl

I have 2 *openvpn-client@* services (*openvpn-client@df* and *openvpn-client@sp*) configured in my machine. I don't want them automatically started at boot. But I want to be able to manually start them whenever I need them.

The problem is that in Fedora 38 enabling the *openvpn-client@* services creates the *openvpn-client@df.service* symlink:

```
# systemctl enable openvpn-client@df
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn-client@df.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service.
```

and disabling it removes this same symlink:

```
# systemctl disable openvpn-client@df
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn-client@df.service".
```

Without this symlink I can't manually start the service.

Is there a way besides manually creating the symlink to be able to manually start these @ services while keeping them disabled?

Comment: Why do you need the symlink? `systemctl start openvpn-client@df` should work?

Comment: There is nothing requiring the symlink as it is only created when enabling the service to have it start at boot. If there is a malfunction with `systemctl start openvpn-client@df`, the add the output including anything in the logs and also the output of `systemctl status openvpn-client@df` to the question. Either way, it has nothing to do with whether or not the service is enabled.

Comment: I got confused by the fact that autocompletion for `systemctl start openvp...` doesn't work without the link, only with if. Because of that I thought that `systemctl start openvpn-client@df` wouldn't work also and have not even tried it before asking. Thanks!